# Cannot read the arguments from console

Tags: java

I used jarsplice for merge my libs and everything went ok, but when I tried to run game from a console it fails :(

That command doesn't work:

> java -Dhost=localhost -Dport=44444 -jar LG2.jar

Communicate:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexutOfBoundsException: 0 at start.Game.main

This is my main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        AppGameContainer appgc;

        host = args[0];
        port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        try {
            appgc = new AppGameContainer(new Game(gamename));
            // appgc.setDisplayMode(1366, 768, true);
            appgc.setDisplayMode(640, 360, false);

            appgc.start();



        } catch (SlickException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Before that:

```
private static String host;
private static int port;
```

Comment: From memory, they won't be command line arguments sent to your code, but will become system properties you can read from the `System` class (they get passed to the JVM not the Jar).  You could use `java -jar LG2.jar host=localhost port=44444` instead and then you'd be able to read them as command line arguments.

Comment: Same as `java -jar LG2.jar localhost 44444` still not working.

Comment: `java -jar LG2.jar localhost 44444` works fine for me

Comment: @MadProgrammer: +1 You should explain why and add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read parameters from this kind of invocation

```
java -Dhost=localhost -Dport=44444 -jar LG2.jar
```

You must use `System.getProperty("host")`.

Comment: Hmm... getting host looks ok, but for port I have a new Exception:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexutOfBoundsException: 1 at start.Game.main`

I tried 
`port = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port"));`

and

`port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);`

Comment: You must use System.getProperty("posrt"); and remove all the other args operations

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at start.Game.main(Game.java:67)`

EDIT: Maybe i should write this with different combination, but what it should look like?

Comment: @p__d No your combination seems fine. System.getProperty("port") should not return null.